# Installing Visual Studio 2022 side by side with 2019. What happens to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB)?

Tags: visual-studio

Installing Visual Studio 2022 side by side with 2019. What happens to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB)? Does it get overwritten with latest version? Can they both exist but with different instance names?